# What is the package name of the Worklight Flight Ticket Sample App?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

In order to run the excellent Flight Ticket Sample App 
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/12_04_Running_jQuery_Mobile_based_Flight_Ticket_Sample.pdf

I need to supply the package name of the Flight Ticket Sample app on the Android developer website:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

What is package name and where do I find it in the app?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Where does it say that you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name is not required in order to run a Worklight application. I am also unaware of any setting you need to enable in the GMC console together with a package name in order to run an app.

Where do you see this requirement? (the PDF does not mention this either).
What are you trying to enable?

**Edit**: based on the comment to the answer...

To enable push notifications support, you are not required at all to provide the package name in the GCM console.

These are the steps to follow in the GCM console:

1. Create a new project. The `project number` is the `senderId` that you use in Worklight
2. Go to API and Auth > APIs and enable "Google Cloud Messaging for Android"
3. Go to API and Auth > Credentials > Public API access and create a new "API Key" > "Browser". You do not need to add any information, only click "next next next". Use the provided `API key` as the `pushSender` in Worklight.

Comment: The Google Android page http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html explains how to create a Google API project and Obtain an API Key. I obtain a Project Number which I will use as my GCM sender ID. Then this page https://cloud.google.com/console/project/apps~alfflask/apiui/credential says that "Accept requests from an Android application with one of the certificate fingerprints and package names listed below" and gives an example with a package name.